# TeXLive 2019 Debian: Pst-plots wrong axes label positioning

Tags: pst-plot

The following code produces the attached image: the x and y labels are put exactly at the centre of the axes. I can reproduce the error using TeXmaker 5.0.3 and running `xelatex` on my terminal; I run the TeXlive distro. packed with Debian Buster.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(5,5)
\psaxes{}(0,0)(4,4)[$x$,0][$y$,0]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The error persists no matter what value I write in for the angle. As far as I can see I am not giving any erroneous arguments. Is it my TeXlive distro? PSTricks' version is 2.97 and `pst-plot` is version 1.92, according to my log file. I'd really like to understand what is happening with this code. Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: I just  noticed this also happens with `\rput` and `\uput`; no matter what coordinate I give those commands, their arguments are always typeset at `(0,0)`. I was going to try downloading CTAN's versions of the packages, but they are the versions I have. Help!

Comment: On my TeXLive 2019 I cannot reproduce the issue. I tried both `latex` and converted the dvi to pdf, and compilation with `xelatex`. In both cases `x` and `y` are where they are presumably supposed to be, i.e. not at the origin. So you may want to update your TeX installation.

Comment: I tried, but it is at the latest version. I also notice it happens with both the `\rput` and `\uput` commands! I need help! :/

Comment: I also have versions 2.97 and 1.92, respectively. (But I also do not really use PSTricks any more, so maybe some of the active users know more.)

Comment: Probably you are using an old xdvipdfmx and Ghostscript
newer than version 9.27.
In the case where Ghostscript version is newer than 9.27,
such as gs-9.50, xdvipdfmx version should be 20191114 or
newer.  Further, there should be `-dDELAYSAFER` in the
D section in `texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg`.
If you install TeX Live 2020 pretest, your problem
is resolved.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto My dvipdfmx version is 20190824, so this might be it. The string `dDELAYSAFER` is where you said it should be: https://pastebin.com/Y2hhRtkG. Is there a way to use the newest version of the package by putting the file on my directory? What I mean is: once the relevant file is there, how do I use it instead of the packaged version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying to downgrade ghostscipt as per Akira's comments above, I ran `latex > dvips > ps2pdf`, both on terminal and on TeXmaker, and the issue is gone. So I guess this should be the way to commpile documents with `PSTricks` until TeXLive 2020 is packaged on Debian.
[image]

Comment: Always `latex > dvips` is the best way to use `PSTricks`.
`PSTricks` for `XeTeX` is a limited extension. There are
several `PSTricks` examples which don't work with XeTeX even
with the new xdvipdfmx.
In these cases, we can use `PSTricks` in XeTeX by including
pdf images obtained by `latex > dvips > epstopdf`.

Comment: My only concern is opacity, which I use a lot, especially with TikZ. Since I want to use both, XeTeX is my preferred option because the dvips route doesn't respect transparencies.

Comment: Of course, PostScript does not support transparency, so
you have to change the PS file with the transparency
extension into other format, e.g., pdf.
In the dvips route: `latex > dvips > ps2pdf`, you can obtain
transparent pdf image which can be included by
`ps2pdf -dDELAYSAFER test.ps test.pdf` in the case of
gs-9.50. Your gs-9.52 is known to have a bug in `pdfwrite`
driver, so you cannot obtain transparent pdf both by the
above method and by `PSTricks` for `XeTeX`.