# No transparency with Asymptote

Tags: asymptote, transparency

I used the code [here](https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/gallery/transparency.asy) and compiled in my computer, with the result as seen in the picture (this was compiled using PDFLaTeX -> Asy -> PDFLaTeX; neither XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX nor dvips -> ps2pdf solve this). For comparison I also did it using TikZ and transparency works fine. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\pagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{asypicture}{name=1}
%\begin{asy}
unitsize(1cm);

fill(shift(1.5dir(120))*unitcircle,green+opacity(0.75));
fill(shift(1.5dir(60))*unitcircle,red+opacity(0.75));
fill(unitcircle,blue+opacity(0.75));
label("Asymptote",shift(1.5dir(270))*(0,0));
%\end{asy}
\end{asypicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=0.75]   
\fill[shift={(120:1.5)},green] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[shift={(60:1.5)},red] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\fill[blue] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\node at (270:1.5) {TikZ};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I tried using the `asymptote` and `asypictureB` packages. I had a somewhat similar [issue with PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537010/texlive-2019-debian-pst-plots-wrong-axes-label-positioning#comment1356787_537010); the user Akira Kakuto pointed out that this was due to a bug with both Ghostscript and xdvipdfmx (versions 9.52 and 20190824, respectively; as packaged in Debian's TeXLive 2019). Is this related to that bug? I found [this report](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/77), so apparently the GS hypothesis stands. Is there any way of properly diagnosing this  (that is, to be sure it is a bug with GS)? Or to solve it? Thanks!

[image: Asy vs. TikZ]

Comment: For me it works fine using the `asymptote` package (v1.33) and compiling with `pdflatex`, `asy -nosafe yourfile-1.asy`, `pdflatex` again. Note the `nosafe`, as also mentioned in the Github thread. My versions are somewhat older, Asymptote version 2.41, Ghostscript version 9.26, all installed using Debian packages for Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe you could try running just `asy -nosafe` on the example `.asy` file, see if the issue is there or somewhere in the LaTeX chain?

Comment: No joy with the `-nosafe` option, I regret to say.

Comment: similar problems (Debian sid, asymptote svn version). Transparency is ok with svg output.

Comment: It works OK under My Windows, except that the Asymptote image is a bit lower in the vertical direction. Please not that you should remove the `%\begin{asy}` and `%\end{asy}` inside the `asypicture` environment, it will cause compiler errors when building the asy code.

Comment: @O.G. Indeed, it works with SVG output; however, the result is not scalable (it is pixelated on zoom).

Comment: `asy` code compiles just fine with the current version (2.65)
and `gs-9.26`.
Also, you have `%\begin{asy}` in the asy code,
and `%` does not start a comment in the `Asymptote` language.

Comment: Issue here : https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/155

Comment: Hi, @O.G. I have attach a pdf in the github issue, it looks like under Windows, transparency is OK, but it does have other issues.