# PST: rput not placing content at all (regression with texlive 2019)

Tags: pstricks

This is a MWE using `\rput` in full-page picture to put text to the middle of the page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=100mm,paperwidth=100mm,margin=0mm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
    \psset{unit=1mm}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(\paperwidth,\paperheight)
        \rput[bl](50mm,50mm){abc}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image: resulting page]

This was compiled with xelatex on TeXlive 2019.202000218 (as packaged in Ubuntu 20.04). I am quite sure `\rput` used to work  correctly as a more complex document, where this was used, is now broken and used to work (= `abc` was placed correctly) before the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 and related TEXlive packages.

Is there a problem on my side? Is there some fix for this?

Thanks!

**PS:** compiling via `latex` → `dvips` places the text correctly.

Comment: I have no problem (except a small error on the horizontal placement). How did you compile?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just `xelatex file.tex`. Same as few years back when it worked.

Comment: I also compiled with xelatex. Perhaps you should update to TeX Live 2020?

Comment: Just tried pasting the code to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_latex_editor.php and after hitting "preview", I get PDF with the same error as shown above.

Comment: I would like to understand the cause. Installing non-packaged version of TeXlive is a burden; I used to do that but avoid it now, especially because of cross-machine compatibility. Surely there is only something small I am missing?

Comment: What do you mean with non-packaged? As far as I know, all versions of TeX Live are packaged. Unless you mean Ubuntu-packaged? Also, don't you have TeX Live package manager installed?

Comment: Correct, I meant ubuntu-packaged (as opposed to TeX-live, which is packaged, but using its own package manager).

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to wait for a Ubuntu update. Meanwhile, maybe you can try the classic way: `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf`.

Comment: Oops, I need fontspec in the real document (custom OTF). So `latex` is a no-go.

Comment: Duplicate of this one (same problem): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537010/texlive-2019-debian-pst-plots-wrong-axes-label-positioning

Comment: I see. As a workaround, can't you compile  such a code the classic way as a standalone document, and incorporate the resulting .pdf via `\includegraphics`?

Comment: That would be difficult, as the text (with OTF) must be a part of the pstricks image. I used filed from texlive (see the answer) and it works fine now. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue is described in [TeXLive 2019 Debian: Pst-plots wrong axes label positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537010/texlive-2019-debian-pst-plots-wrong-axes-label-positioning#comment1356787_537010) (and explained in the comment linked) and comes from version mismatch between ghostscript and dvipdfmx.

It was solved by overwriting ubuntu-packaged `/usr/bin/xdvipdfmx` binary and its config `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg` with corresponding files from TeXLive 2020.

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the existing config file! Use an own one and save it into `/usr/local/share/texmf/...`. Then it won't be overwritten with an update.

Comment: I hope the update will be texlive 2020, having correct defaults already.

Comment: that is fixed in 2020